# Tool to make iPhone apps

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone and know about xcode.
But i have read that various tools are also available to make iPhone apps...
which are also accepted by apple....
I want to start one of them but don't know which one should be the best and easy one....
i have knowledge of iPhone and objective c....and know java also.....

i am basically interested in making games and some web applications....

please also tell about their cost...because i don't want to spend money on them...

please help...

Comment: I think XCode is best and enough for any kind of iPhone development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the game side there a several libs and tools you can find but it really depends on what you want to do.

usually people only try 2D games on phones so I recommend looking into [cocos 2D](http://cocos2d.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the best apps and if you have a mac, then use apple's xcode, as you have an understanding of objective C.  The apple development program, which you have to enroll in in order to submit apps to the app store, costs $100/year.  If you don't want to pay for a mac, then go with flash cs5.  I just made an iPhone app with it.  It works great.  It costs only $299 - $599

Answer (score 0):

On the web application side, you can use good old HTML, CSS, and jQuery!

http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/

Also, Apple has relaxed their restrictions on using cross-compilation tools to create apps, so that you CAN use Flash, etc to create iPhone apps.

Comment: i was taking about tools similar to xcode...like corona and some other are there but...i want to spend my time on easy one ....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop web apps, try sencha and JQuery Mobile.

Comment: i want to like to chat you can you come on skype...

Comment: reply here and i will post my id for few time here if you want...

Comment: Yogesh, What do you wish to know? If at all you feel what ever you want to know might help others, it is always better to discuss in the forum so that every one gets to know it, if you dont find it comfortable discussing here, you can contact me personally.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you wish to make the application on a PC or you prefer C++ over Objective C is the [Airplay SDK](http://www.airplaysdk.com/). It also has the advantage of supporting multiple platforms.